# Android: Replacing navigation bar icons with dots

Tags: android

I've seen a number of apps on Android that replace the navigation bar icons (the triangle, for back, circle, and square) with dots.  The button is still there, just less intrusive.  Good for games and video apps.

How is this done?  I can't find an api for it other than immersive mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `View.setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE)` on one of the Views in your Activity.

Or, if you want to set it on the window:

`getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);`

To hide completely:
`getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);`

[Android View documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility(int))

[Relevant Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231336/android-4-0-setting-system-ui-flag-low-profile-system-ui-flag-hide-navigation)